# iPad Will Not Charge or Charges Very Slowly

Tags: ipad, usb, battery, charging

I recently dug an old ipad out of storage (the model number is A1395), and I would like to begin using it again. Unfortunately, it is having significant trouble charging.

When I first attempted to turn it on by long-pressing the power button, nothing happened. After plugging it in with the original (potentially damaged) cable nothing happened still. When I plugged the USB end of the cable into a new charger for an Android phone, I saw a red battery logo which I assumed meant that it needed time to charge. I then left it for a few hours, and then attempted to turn it on. It worked, and was charged to 37%. This percentage, however, continued going down even while plugged into the same android charger. IOS does not show a charging indication when either the android or original ipad charger are being used.

Is this something I can fix easily and cheaply (ie. no apple store, replacement parts, ifixit, etc.)? Should I try getting a new cable (Is [this](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B00K4DTTLY) the right one for that model)? I expect the battery to be worse-off after all this time being stored at who knows what charge, but I would expect it to still run without issue from wall power.

Some things I have tried/Notes:

- Plugging the ipad into a computer with powered usb ports that charge my android phone without issue does not fix this. This is not an apple computer.
- The 30 pin charging port appears to be clean, but I can't get a good look inside. Is there some specific cleaning method I should use?
- I do not have any other apple chargers available.
- I couldn't find any other information other than Apple's official documentation, from which I tried each suggestion that is sufficiently described and does not cost money. If it costs more than a few dollars to fix this, it isn't worth it to me.
- When I turn the ipad off and charge it with the phone charger, it charges albeit very slowly.
- The difference between the wattage of the ipad and phone chargers according to their labeling is 0.11 wats., with the ipad charger having slighly more.
- I found another 30 pin <-> usb cable lying around, using it has no apparent effect.

Comment: The iPad chargers have twice the output power of a phone charger or PC USB port - Mac USB can provide the higher power needed. I'd say first test would be an actual iPad charger.

Comment: @tetsujin I tried an actual ipad charger -- it provides no power whatsoever it seems. When I tried an *android* phone charger, it charges. This android phone chargers labeling says that it provides a different amount of power than an iPhone charger.

Comment: So apparently the first charger is dead, the 2nd provides half power.

Comment: @tetsujin Are you saying the labeling on the second one is incorrect? Isn't that illegal? Also, where can I get a good replacement charger. I'm not interested in paying 4 times the price to get an official apple one (that is the 30 pin cable markup) -- something compatible will be just fine.